# Radio frequency Exposure

Tags: frequency

CAN ANY ONE explain why I can hear perfectly timed identically patterned 24,/7 as of 7 months ago. Doc confirmed healthy, perfect hearing. Home 100% inspected and signed off with documentation, electric, plumbing, gas, the whole 9. No smart meters nothing. I've fixed/replaced anything and ever thing. Its not my house and I'm healthy doc certified. I winds up like levels of exact tones on a repeditive exactly the same timing cycle and ramps up louder and louder like every our. Real bad like 4am noonish midnight.  Got hours of audio can clearly hear it when gain is turned up. And have hours of spectrum graphs to show db timing db and hz. All low 0- like 21000 then instantly drops straight line.. im about to sling my brains on the wall its hurts my stomach when it get out like I'm getting sized open and makes my skin itch and I can feel it all over only when it gets intense and loud. Again I'm getting ready to sling my brains on the wall I can't take it much longer

Comment: My first inclination is to be worried about what you are going through. And I do NOT discount it. If you are feeling these things, then you are and no one can dispute it. Something may actually be happening. It may be something that can be addressed, too. I don't know. But what you are describing also doesn't seem like anything we can help with, either. I wish I could suggest something. But I can't think of anything specific to help. I'm sorry.

Comment: Very difficult to figure out over the internet. Maybe sleeping with earplugs could provide some relief? Just a thought.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about electronic design.

Comment: It may be tinnitus? Or did you have dental surgery? Perhaps some Valium might help.

Comment: What frequency is this tone ? And what is the equivalent dBA when an external sound matches it? does it wawa when another tone is played near exact same frequency? What is the pattern?  Does a tinfoil hat make it worse or better?

Comment: Its multiple tones frequency low mainly 20hz and suddenly drops in dn after 21khz peeks like -50 db. In the 40s -60 hz area and same in the 10khz -21 kHz. If you gota drop the thread no problem. I throw my email up real fast. I need to find out how I need to specifically hire to figure this out because its not a home elec job its more IEEE, type.  It never stops. Theres nothing wrongvwith me. Im dick of hearing that. Doc say I'm healthy a a jay bird and my mom hears the same thing but my old man dont. Repeative tones like ex: old skool dial up

Comment: See this is why you can't find studys on low frequency anywhere because the 2% don't matter and every one thinks its a joke. Its like sitting on a ham radio

Comment: (1)  Your question mentions RF, but you say you hear something. So it might be low RF that you barely hear, or high RF that your brain "hears". (2) Perhaps a bad guys has set up a auto RF gun outside your house. You might like to use the following cheap meter to locate the bad guy's device: (!) DIY Rpi Triple Axis RF / EMF Detector (50Hz to 3GHz) using AD8362 / AD8361 Asked 11 months ago Active 11 months ago Viewed 518 times 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112643/diy-rpi-triple-axis-rf-emf-detector-using-ad8362-ad8361/112647#112647

Comment: Kbsortzi@gmail.com  I can send all audio and graphs and spectrum readings

Comment: Exactly ultralow can pen through mountains.  Just trying to figure it out. Maybe I'm sitting in the line of a tower some one just put up or some ones ham close by. Its def low frequency the meters don't lie. And it ain't tinnitus or my health doc says no so if you got jokes save it.

Comment: Is there a sign on your neighbors front lawn that says WWV ?  Is there a 200' antenna tower in their backyard?

Comment: You say you have recordings. So I believe you that it is real. But I have no idea what to tell you to do about it. Move somewhere else. Wear earplugs. And it does seem off-topic so it probably will get closed. But I do sympathize with your suffering. If you didn't have recordings I would suspect tinnitus. (But I am not a doctor and not all that knowledgeable about tinnitus).

Comment: Could it be seismic noise? Any rivers nearby? Hydroelectric powerplants?

Comment: https://www.noiseandhealth.org/article.asp?issn=1463-1741;year=2004;volume=6;issue=23;spage=59;epage=72;aulast=Leventhall

Comment: Another thought: where do you get your tapwater from? Municipal water, or do you have a well? If municipal water, where is the nearest booster pump? If own well, do you have an in-well pump? If you have your own in-well pump, try cutting the power to that when you hear the noise.

Comment: It seems it's acoustic noise and @KS is in good health. 1) For my work with human exposure to EM field, even RF fields can be "rectified" (demodulated) inside human body, and you can hear something due to modulation signal. Same phenomenon is the whistle of GSM mobile in the desk phone next to it. 2) If you were in a metro train, you can hear the modulation of the PWM inverter along thee air conditioning. 3) In general, when you have a trafo or "magnetic" magnetostrition produces doubled harmonics and you hear the 50/60 Hz and harmonics, transmitted by the trafo core and enclosure.

Comment: -- this said, we should have a better description of what is around (which technological systems, which power lines, trafos, inverters and power drives, I don't know  PV system, and the like) and the recordings. Thank you @KS

Comment: you could post the audio recordings on YouTube ... maybe someone could be able to identify the sound

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be ground vibrations as it is worse in the basement and garage floor, but it is also acoustic with broad spectrum noise that ramps up in frequency like a sawtooth sweep according to his description. It’s worse in wind and rain sound it also has the sounds of a variable pitch hundreds of telephone lines resonating in 4 to 8 hr cycles.

### Added:

It’s not that loud for urban background noises that vary alot, but in a quiet rural setting this cyclic noise started last October and is 40 dB above the quiet ambient. ( Not A-weighted levels but recorded on some mobile ?)

It can affect his eye-sight focus at worst and is heard by all with good hearing. Again if you had this noise 40 dB above the ambient, you might complain too at 4 AM, so **this is a broadband spectral analysis problem** with the audio signature of one episode below.  The RF demodulation factor cannot be recorded on this device, so it does not match what he hears over the audio spectrum, yet the recorded levels inside the house are mostly coherent with what he hears being amplitude modulated outside.

——————

I requested some audio files and **it's not loud but it is annoying** when you are supposed to be in a quiet rural setting with no power on and nothing around for miles and it ramps up at 4 am.

- it appears to be a combination rumbling of 57 and 60 Hz with broad modulation that extends with a weak subharmonic at 30 Hz yet a strong harmonic at 90 etc.

So the 3 Hz rumble modulation  is like the aliasing of a 60 Hz induction machine running at 3420 RPM.

Anyone wishes to comment on correlation with industrial noise, alien underground vibrations or RF generation which has not been recorded, feel free to add comments to this.

[image]

He also described it as a screeching sound like an old modem except rising in frequency slowly then repeating ,so that to me sounds like a slow Jacob's Ladder corona arc.

I'm thinking it is corona discharge modulated by the grid current emanating from a transformer or somewhere but I have no good feel for the source of this sound yet.

Also telephone lines have been known to screech from too much gain from negative impedance amps in the line amplifiers but not outdoor acoustic noise.

TBD

I also suggested adding some background sounds of a waterfalls or babbling brook to raise the ambient noise with a better signal for now. To let the ears’ “AGC effects” suppress the rumble and screech.  we can hear over a 120 dB range but not at the same time.  We as humans are hard-pressed to hear a musician turning the page of sheet music if the music is 40 dB louder in the playing of a loud overture.

**But in this case the noise is 40 dB louder than the quiet background and it’s complex yet periodic, industrial grid and RF related.** in an ambient in the middle of nowhere.

Sorry no  theories of magneto-resonant Tesla Power being extracted by Alien UFO’s. But it is a puzzle he is willing to hire a pro to diagnose but doesn’t know any.  I could but live in Toronto and there’s travel restrictions.  I once helped a guy in Georgia detect hidden GPS tracking devices and transponders for those who wanted to start a privacy business using a 10GHz Spectrum Analyzer.

Here’s a different event with a time waterfall spectro-graph

[image]

Comment: the local power utility logs could be the source of additional information

Comment: Apparently Detroit Power DGA came out 5 times and recorded  different frequencies like 60, 100 105 110 120 ! I asked him to trace the noise with a SW or AM radio and point to weakest or strongest direction to locate radiation sources as it could be a partial discharge or corona arc somewhere local or on DT bushings . But the rumble of 57 and 60 Hz sounds like an industrial arc and motor intermodulation from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

From Tony's answer, it seems to be low frequency.

Problem with low frequency are:

- Our ears can't locate low frequency sound accurately, so you can't hear where it comes from
- It will create standing waves resonance in your rooms, and "organ pipe" resonances in your corridors, so it'll be loud or absent in various random places in your house
- It also propagates in masonry

I've had this problem in an appartment, it sounded like some loud bass. So I got a stethoscope, and looked like an idiot sticking it to the walls everywhere in the building.  The source was a neighbor's ventilation fan that was full of dust, but only on one side, so it wobbled and generated that constant bass note. Vaccuming the dust out fixed the issue.

So, it could be:

Generated inside the house or on your property by an electrical device, either mains powered or battery powered. Or animals, or the wind, etc.

Or coming from somewhere else.

And it could be sound, or vibrations, or RF interference that is then turned into sound by something. Either an appliance in your house, or something else.

You need a divide and conquer approach.

Since you recorded it, you know it exists. But did the recorder pick up sound or RF?

Turn off the power to your house at the main panel and make sure the meter stops counting, so nothing is powered. Still hearing the noise?

Put a stethoscope to the walls, to the floors, then outside, try hard materials in contact with the ground like the patio. Hear something?

Maybe there's a mining/drilling operation in the area...

Comment: The noise exists with all power off and is acoustic dependent on concrete subfloors in basement and garage are loudest yet worse with wind and rain noise.  Also the recording device is different in HF content suggesting RF also like corona modulated sweeps.  Detroit power has also noticed events in 5 visits but offer no solution. And is 5 miles from HWY and in a completely isolated RURAL  area. He was a welder and HVAC guy by trade.

Comment: This is so weird, I hope he figures it out...